# Show only one scale bar unit when printing with ArcGIS API for JavaScript

Tags: arcgis-js-api

I am trying to get rid of the "Miles" / "Feet" scale bar unit and only display "Kilometers" / "Meters" when exporting a map as an image, but have not found a way of doing this.

Here is a [live sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/widget_print_esri_request.html) from the ArcGIS API documentation where `layoutOptions` are specified with `scalebarUnit` as "Miles".

`scalebarUnit` is supposed to be defined as one of 'Miles', 'Kilometers', 'Meters' or 'Feet' (as documented [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/printtemplate-amd.html#layoutoptions)), but no matter what I specify there's always both metric and English units displayed.

[image]

*(Want to remove the highlighted scale bar unit.)*

For completeness, here's relevant parts of the code I use;

```
const pt = new PrintTemplate();
pt.layout = this.layout + " " + this.orientation;
pt.format = this.fileType;
pt.preserveScale = this.preserveScale;
pt.layoutOptions = { legendLayers: [], scalebarUnit: "Kilometers", titleText: this.titleText }
pt.exportOptions = { width: 500, height: 400, dpi: 96 };

const pp = new PrintParameters();
pp.map = this.theMap;
pp.outSpatialReference = new SpatialReference(3006);
pp.template = pt;

const printTask = new PrintTask(this.printUrl);
printTask.execute(pp,
    (response) => this.onImageExportComplete(response.url),
    (error) => {
        this.setSubmitIsInProgress(false);
        this.errorCb(error);
    });
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but for me this seems impossible because the printing is made on server side and you can't change that behavior with any layoutOptions